# Placing a div at the bottom of another div

Tags: css

I'm trying to do jquery pagination, however I'm having a problem keeping the navigator on the bottom, even with `clear: both`.

[image]

The problem is that the navigation div `<div class="alt_page_navigation"></div>` needs to be right where `</ul>` ends and cannot be in another div, or else the pagination get's broken.

Another problem is that because the page is dynamic, I don't know the width of the `alt_page_navigation` beforehand.

[Here's a live page example](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/littlething/), I've tried everything google spit up, to no avail.
If anyone knows of a simple solution, please let me know :)

Thank you :))

Comment: Tried absolute positioning? is that an option?

Comment: Yup. Making the wrapper `relative` and the paginator `absolute` breaks my `inline-block` code which centers the navigator. That's why I said that because the content is dynamic and I don't know the width of the paginator beforehand, I have a problem :(

Comment: @pufAmuf Then put the paginator inside an absolutely positioned block that has left:0 and text-align:center.

Comment: @pufAmuf There's no reason that `position:relative` should affect your `inline-block` layout. That's a separate issue.

Comment: What are your absolute markup requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear won't work with your inline-block display, but you need that for centering.

Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best) for creating a clearing div, then put

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

between your products and your pager.

Answer (score 1):

Put padding at the bottom equal to the height of your nav, and position like so:

```css
.wrapper { position:relative; padding-bottom:1.5em }
.nav     { height:1.5em; position:absolute; bottom:0 }
```

For example: http://jsfiddle.net/CwrMq/

---

But there's no reason to use absolute positioning, either; just make it a proper `display:block` item. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/CwrMq/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your `.alt_page_navigation` div has `display: inline-block` set on it. If you delete this line in css - your div will clear the floats. If you want its content to be in the center of the page simply add `text-align: center` to it and make sure that its content is `inline-block` (now your `a` are block-level). You can see the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6FNH6/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution i tend to use in situations like this.

Your paginator needs to go inside a container that positions it horizontally

See this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/94MwF/1/

Basically you are using text-align to horizontally center it, and position absolute to put it at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks Sam, however as I noted above; putting the pager inside another div breaks the paging.